# Generate secure channel between card and terminal

Tags: java-me, smartcard, javacard

I want to generate secure channel between card and terminal. This is my code:

```
    final static byte INIT_UPDATE       = (byte) 0x50;
    final static byte EXT_AUTHENTICATE  = (byte) 0x82;
    SecureChannel sc;

    public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
        return;
        }
       byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
         short inlength = 0;

        try
        {
        switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {

       case INIT_UPDATE:
             case EXT_AUTHENTICATE:
                    makeSecureChannel(apdu);
                break;
     }   
  catch (CryptoException e) 
     {
           short r = e.getReason();
          ISOException.throwIt(r);
      }
```

}

```
    private void makeSecureChannel(APDU apdu) 
{

    byte[] buf = apdu.getBuffer();
    byte cla = buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA];
    byte ins = buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS];

    try
    {
    apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
    if(ins == INIT_UPDATE)
    {
        sc = GPSystem.getSecureChannel();     
    }

    short len = sc.processSecurity(apdu);

    apdu.setOutgoing();
    apdu.setOutgoingLength(len);
    apdu.sendBytes(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, (short) len);   
    }
    catch(APDUException ex1)
    {
        ISOException.throwIt(ex1.getReason());
    }     
}
```

when I send command `80 50 20 00 08 01 15 6A 2A F5 64 87 CF` I get error `6a88` and when i send command `00 50 20 00 08 01 15 6A 2A F5 64 87 CF` I get error `6e00`.
Can every body help me?

Comment: Can you localize the error to a specific line of code? Can you debug? Are you sure your card supports this Global Platform API call?

Comment: Did you select your applet before sending the APDU command? Do you have a key set on your card with key version == 0x20? If no, replace 0x20 with 0x00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statusword `6E00` is not very interesting. It means that you're sending an incorrect CLA (class) byte. And that's because INITIALIZE UPDATE is not defined in ISO 7816, so it is a proprietary command. And proprietary commands must have their proprietary bit set. So class byte `80` is the only correct one.

That out of the way, let's focus on the response of INIT UPDATE: `6A88`. `6A88` means "reference data not found". This probably means that the key referenced by P1 and P2 do not match. Put both P1 and P2 to `00` to make sure that the key is automatically selected (and check the "key information" in the response data if you want to explicitly select the key version in P1).